How to search Google Tasks
The problem is that there doesn't appear to be a search option for tasks.
This was originally asked here - https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/220012593?hl=en - but the question has been closed so I can't add any feedback there.

One way to search Task Titles (and any visible detail) is to:

From Calendar, select 'Switch to Tasks' (top right)
select the lists to view that you want to search
then use the browser search (Ctrl-F in Windows+Chrome) to find relevant titles

note that this will find also titles that are 'off screen'
but will not find completed tasks (unless you 'open' them manually for each list, possibly multiple times)
this also won't search the detail of a task (except for a small bit of visible text)



I hope this is useful to someone - at least it is better than nothing...
